# Question about Static and Dynamic Scoping Problem

Tags: pascal, scoping

Can you confirm my answer for the following code:

```
procedure main
var x,y,z;

    procedure sub1
       begin
        var x,z 
        x := 6;
        z := 7;
        sub2();
        x := y*z + x;
        print(x);       
      end
    procedure sub2
      begin
        var x,y
        x := 1;
        y := x+z+2;
        print(y);       
      end
begin
    x := 1; y:=3; z:=5;
    sub1();
    sub2();
end
```

I got:

- static:

  ```
  8
  27
  ```
- dynamic:

  ```
  10
  27
  ```

Is that correct?

Comment: The program refuses to compile here. Var blocks within begin..end ? sub2 being called for declaration?  Doing sub1(); is not proper pascal too, and while most compilers will accept it, your teacher might not.  What is print() ?

Comment: The above code isn't valid Pascal. Surely you have written it incorrectly.

Comment: I agree with the comments about the wrong syntax constructs used, but I think the question is more theoretical in nature than practical. The example is clear, albeit syntactically incorrect (however, there should probably be some sort of disclaimer on that head).

Answer (score 0):

***If*** Pascal supported dynamic scoping, then your analysis would be correct, as far as it goes. The `z` variable declared in `sub1` would *shadow* the one declared in `main`, even within `sub2`. But the `x` declared in `sub2` would not affect the value of the `x` declared in `sub1`, so `sub1` still uses the original value 6 when it reads `x` after calling `sub2`.

Your analysis is incomplete, though. There should be *three* values printed each time, not just two. The third value printed should be 8 in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

I've no idea what static vs dynamic means. Pascal always uses the variable in the innermost scope. If you use that, then 8,27 is the result.  I don't know how you came to the other result (everything global?)